# Nonbraided rigid monoidal category where left and right duals coincide

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, monoidal-categories, braided-tensor-categories

In a braided rigid monoidal category $(\mathcal{M},\otimes)$ left and right duals coincide. What is an example of a rigid monoidal category where left and right duals coincide but there exist no braiding for the category?

Comment: Modules over an involutive Hopf algebra, which is not quasitriangular.

Comment: It may be useful to know that the standard term for when left and right duals coincide in a coherent way is "pivotal category". Any pivotal category which is braided is automatically [spherical](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9310164). So any non-spherical pivotal category will give an example which does not have any braiding.

Comment: @Bugs Bunny: Does left and right duals coinciding in $_H-mod$ imply the Hopf algebra $H$ s quasi-triangular?

Comment: @Fofi Konstantopoulou  No way.

Comment: Adding to Tobias Fritz' comment, it's worth mentioning that a braided rigid category is _not_ pivotal in general. Left and right duals a priori only coincide as functors, but not as monoidal functors, which is really the compatibility condition one would like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest example is G-graded vector spaces where G is a non-abelian group.

Comment: Is it clear that this category does not admit a braiding?

Comment: The fusion rules aren't commutative!

Comment: Yes, of course!